# InstallHandler runs under a special ghost user. What rights does it have?

Tags: apex, managed-package, sharing, scheduled-apex, postinstall

When you install a managed package with a post-install script, Salesforce creates a special ghost user under which all of the post install activities occur. I think this is undocumented. [Here are some details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22336/320).

This can be great from an audit point of view (you can see which package has 'touched' all the data). But can problematic in several examples:

- Certain objects are inaccessible by SOQL (I've found `CronTrigger` and `ApexClass` so far)
- Scheduled Jobs (and any code they call) will forever run under the post-install context,
- Batch Jobs execute as the post-install user and suffer the same issues above,

I've tried querying the user by id in SOQL to no avail, and the debug log monitor don't record anything.

**How crippled is this special ghost user? Does he have a documented profile?**

Edit: I've emailed myself some *post install context* `UserInfo` return values. Interesting ones in bold:

- **UserType: `LicenseManager` (Aha! Who knows what privileges he has!?)**
- **ProfileId: `00eF0000000XXXXAAA` (viewing URL gives Insufficient Privileges!)**
- **UserName: `033g0000000XXXXAAA@00df0000000XXXXAAA` (package-id@org-id)**
- **UserId: `005F0000003XXXXAAA` (viewing URL gives Insufficient Privileges!)**
- Email: `noreply@salesforce.com`
- DefaultCurrency: `USD`
- FirstName: `null`
- Language: `en_US`
- LastName: `[managed package name]`
- Locale: `en_US`
- Name: `[managed package name]`
- OrganizationId: `[installing org id]`
- OrganizationName: `[installing company name]`
- SessionId: `null`
- TimeZone: `America/Los_Angeles`
- UiTheme: `Theme3`
- UiThemeDisplayed: `Theme3`
- UserRoleId: `null`

Comment: This is a great question! Can someone from Salesforce know the answer?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

After trial and error investigation, it appears the InstallHandler can run with **unlimited privileges** given one special condition; the `InstallHandler` implementor must have `without sharing` annotation.

Running `without sharing` allows the install user context to:

- view all data
- modify all data
- interrogate system data (like `CronTrigger` and `ApexClass`)

The install user context cascades into any Batch Apex and Scheduled Apex jobs that are invoked as part of the post install script. If those classes are **also** annotated `without sharing`, it offers the capability of long-running "super user" processes.

###### [Gennadiy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/24199/gennadiy): System objects are not available when script fires on upgrade (by manual or by push)

Comment: Glad to see you managed to get to an answer on this. This is incredibly important undocumented information.

Comment: Just make sure nobody deletes the jobs it schedules or you'll have to reinstall your app!

Comment: Or upgrade ;) @ca_peterson

Comment: Where did you get this information? It's not possible to query on the Profile or User record of the InstallScript Ghost User to ensure for "sure" what Permissions it has, so other than trial and error, how do you know that this user has "unlimited privileges"?

Comment: Many thanks for yor post, but unfortunately it looks like it is not possible to query local (not managed) custom settings so it's not 'View all data' after all. [More information here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68878/custom-settings-in-subscribers-org-not-accessible-by-managed-code)

Comment: So what is Salesforce.com Security Review Teams stance on using WITHOUT SHARING in this context? If you do proper SOC you have your SOQL / DML that resides outside the invocation point (PostInstaller Apex Class in this case). Often SFDC Security Review will reject a package that uses WITHOUT SHARING even with valid business justification.

Comment: On the PostInstaller Class is the way I interprete this. But proper SOC you would use Domain objects which encapsulate the SOQL / DML which are used throughout codebase, either Controllers/Extensions, Batch Apex, Trigger Hanlders, ETC. My point is if you have reusable code in a managed package that has WIHTOUT SHARING Security Review will flag that and you have to document your business use case which is incredibly painful and time consuming discussion to have with them. Has this goine through a Sec REview as the approved solution?

Comment: Practice at BigAss is to only specify the sharing keyword on entry point classes. Have you considered making your domain layer to be sharing agnostic, so it inherits the contextual behavior of the calling code? @CoryCowgill

Comment: Yes, that again though gets flagged by SFDC Security Review as it does not have WITH SHARING so they flag it for review. Apex classes that do not have the sharing keywords execute with permission of the calling class, which SFDC Security Review treats as WITHOUT SHARING and you have to document and do a review with them.

Comment: My specific ask is has anyone gone through Security Review using WITHOUT SHARING for PostInsaller Classes and discussed this with a SFDC Security Engineer for approval. Or am I the only unlucky one having issues with SFDC Security Review and explaining business case for WITHOUT SHARING.

Comment: I went through sec review, have my installhandler marked as without sharing and did not get flagged.

Comment: We also have a number of managed packages that have gone through security review with InstallHandler classes annotated as "without sharing". I think we had to justify it the first time, but haven't had any trouble with subsequent reviews. That being said, we STILL run into issues where post-install code doesn't work right due to some obscure/opaque permission issue that doesn't occur when the same code is run as a regular user. Please up-vote this idea if you find this whole business as annoying as I do: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DpREAA0

Comment: @bigassforce I am using some batch classes inside the post-install script. Since post-install uses a special Ghost user, Would there be any impact if I will use 'with sharing' in my batch class?

Comment: @Aakriti.G I think "with sharing" context is constrained but do try. If you're unable to query something you need (by trial and error), then wrap that specific SOQL in a well documented "without sharing" inner class to get it through security review.

Comment: Hello guys. I found one more thing related to access to system objects (e.g., CronTrigger) when sharing is enabled. If script fires on upgrade (no matter manual or by push), then system objects are not available. If it fires on the first installation, it still has access to such objects.