# Delete Group using Apex

Tags: apex, public-group, uninstall

Trying to delete groups and queues within Apex code when executing an uninstall script, Salesforce raises me this error:

*DML operation DELETE not allowed on Group*

Although this is pretty clear error, I am able to delete groups using the Developer Console, querying for groups and using the syntax `delete groups` (where groups is a list of the *Group* object).

Is it really impossible to delete groups using Apex? Should I use some fancy @future annotation to the method that deletes them? Or I really am unable to delete groups, and have to delete the *GroupMember* object instead?

Comment: I think you can use Apex to delete Groups - a test proves it, so it looks like it's possibly something to do with the uninstall script and the ghost user used to run it? This is in interesting post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have that might give you some ideas?

Comment: Did it work?
Adding 'without sharing' dint work for me? any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: No. It didn't work either. In the end, we switched our method, and created a Visualforce page to handle the delete of the components that would need to be removed if the user wanted to uninstall the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that this is happening is because within your [UninstallHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_uninstall_handler.htm), the user in context is a temporary user that is used when performing managed package operations. This user type is `LicenseManager`. I'm assuming for security purposes, they do not have access to many dml operations on setup objects.

We tried a similar thing in our uninstall handler to remove our packaged permission sets from users. That also fails in the same way yours does.

I haven't tried it, but I assume that calls to `@future` will either throw an exception, or be discarded because the uninstall process needs to run synchronously right before the actual uninstall.

[According to this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36474/323), adding the `without sharing` keyword may get this temporary user the appropriate permissions but obviously, without creating a package and testing DML on groups, it's hard to tell if it will work.

Comment: I'm going to try the 'without sharing' solution soon. If I succeed, I will update this question and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I tried making the uninstall handler class 'without sharing' but that does not seem to work either. Also, the uninstall fails when trying to uninstall the managed package. But if I go to the uninstall handler class and click on edit and cancel, I am able to uninstall the package, but the script doesn't delete the intended records.

So, no, adding 'without sharing' to the uninstall handler class does not make the records delete either. I believe deletion is just not allowed as a part of uninstall.

Answer (score -3):

You can run the following Apex in developer console.

```
Group g = [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM Group 
           Where DeveloperName = 'Test_Group' LIMIT 1];
delete g;
```

Comment: I know I can run it via developer console, but I want to run it in a class, inside a managed package. When I tried to do it, SF raised the error I told in the question.