# Inserts of ObjectPermission or FieldPermission fail in an InstallHandler - is there an InstallHandler alternative?

Tags: managed-package, permissions, permission-sets, package-install, postinstall

Code that inserts `ObjectPermission` and `FieldPermission` SObjects through normal insert calls (on a permission set that is also created) works fine in unit tests and through the developer console. That code is implemented in `Queueable`s to ensure it runs in a transaction that is after the `InstallHandler` transaction (though that is probably not relevant).

When run as part of a package install through the `InstallHandler`, errors of this nature are returned whatever the mix of standard and custom objects/fields is:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> CANNOT_MODIFY_MANAGED_OBJECT, Cannot modify managed object:
> entity=FieldPermissions

So it seems like the "special" user that install packages does not have the rights to do that DML. Does that user have the rights to modify the same dat through the Metadata or Tooling APIs? (I think not if this [Unable to do callout from PostInstall Script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248133/unable-to-do-callout-from-postinstall-script) is correct.)

Comment: I suspect you might be asking an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What's the background behind this question?

Comment: @sfdcfox Fair point. The goal is to add CRUD permission for a custom field that is a master-detail relationship to a standard field. Such relationships are stripped when a permission set is packaged, and we want to avoid the manual setup step of adding the permission after install. Certainly interested in thoughts on other ways to handle this, and ultimately if it has to be manual then so be it. This originally came in as a bug report - that setup step was missed.

Comment: I don't have an easy way to test, but two thoughts: (a) if you can use EventBus.publish, you can then kick over to the Automated User, which should have perms to do what you're trying, or (b) use a PostInstallURL that directs to a VF page to finish setting up the org.

Comment: We'll give the Platform Event approach a try. Do you know that `EventBus.publish` works from an `InstallHandler`? And that the default Platform Event user can successfully perform the DML, or is it more an expectation that it should work?

Comment: (a) I have no idea. The documentation doesn't say either way. (b) The Platform Event user should be the Automation User, which I believe does have permission, but again, documentation is scarce. I mean, you can test latter hypotheses easily, just write a PE trigger, see if it sticks. The trickier part is if Install Handler can call PE or not.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I appreciate your candour. We will do the work to find out.