# Developer script exception: Do not have access to view running user

Tags: queryexception, unexpectedexception

I'm trying to debug a "Developer Script Exception".

> Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization:
>   0053000000ARXXX/00D30000000XXX
>
> AccountMasterTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: sObject type 'My_Object__c' is not
>   supported.

Seems like a permission issue, however, when I try to open the ID for the user in salesforce, I get the following error:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Anyone seen something similar or have more info on what might be going on?

Comment: Have you checked the Field-Level Security of that field?

Comment: @HengkyIlawan it's actually an SObject (I had misleadingly replaced with name with `My_Field__c`).

I can check to see if which profiles don't have access, but that doesn't really help.  I need to know which profile is throwing the error and then determine if they SHOULD have access

Comment: if you can't see the User record (and you're an admin), then you're looking at a "system" user. What is the use case where this occurs?

Comment: Did you make sure that the Org ID in Setup matches the Org ID in the email? Is it possible this email came from a Sandbox or another org?

Comment: @sfdcfox Ya, it matches production.  

Assuming it's a system user... what are the possible entry points?

Answer (score 2):

One source of such users is the "package ghost user". When a package post-install script runs, it runs as a user named after the package, who does not appear in the User list that you can view/query.

That user has some funky permissions. See [InstallHandler runs under a special ghost user. What rights does it have?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have)

Usually, this doesn't matter because you write your install handler `without sharing`. However, if you start up a scheduled job in post-install, then that job is owned by the ghost user.

I've had problems where the scheduled job causes a trigger to run, which runs some Apex `with sharing` and then gets an error similar to the one you are seeing now.

Comment: interesting...

Given that this is a trigger on the Account, it's very possible this could be the cause.   Going to leave unanswered for a few more days to see if there are any other possible "ghost user" sources