# Debug Logs for PostInstallHandler SuperUser

Tags: debugging, scheduled-job, postinstall

I have a PostInstallScript (without sharing) that schedules a job which I need to see in Debug Logs. However, the job is run under SuperUser mentioned in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have). I have gone through the answer for it and comments section, but were unable to find any useful information on how to debug my Scheduled Job that runs under this specific user.

This user doesn't appear in the users list in Setup -> Debug Logs, it is neither an Automated Process User, nor Platform Integration User.

Has anyone encountered such a problem? Is there any solution for it?

Note: I have tried to schedule job from method with `@Future` annotation, but no luck.

**UPDATE**

Do **NOT** try to schedule jobs from PostInstallHandler, because somehow SuperUser's permissions are volatile and after Spring '22 relesed it cannot cooperate in scheduled jobs with package custom objects and it throws Exception like (we think that it was connected to **Spring '22** release):

```
Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: .../...

Scheduled job 'SCHEDULED_JOB_NAME' threw unhandled exception.

caused by: line LINE, column COLUMN: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
Class CLASS : DML operation Delete not allowed on MANAGED_PACKAGE_CUSTOM_OBJECT
```

Comment: There is no access to debug logs for the package installer that I ever found, since this uses the "ghost user" which doesn't actually exist, and trying to insert records into the database doesn't help since these changes get rolled back if the installer fails. This **IS** really problematic. As to the "update" in your question, something changed in Spring '22 which broke permissions for the "ghost user". I have a support case (#42085436) open with Salesforce about this. That said, it *is* a bad idea to schedule jobs from the installer because there is no control over the permissions applied.

Comment: It was broken at least one release earlier, because I started to get those errors in December. Thank you for sharing the case number, I will take a look!

Comment: Are you sure you were not using a preview of Spring 22? We were not affected at all until Spring 22, and this is only now hitting all our customers' orgs.

Comment: Yes, I definitely sure, because it was on only 4 our orgs: 2 customer (1 prod and 1 sandbox) and 2 developer orgs of our QA. I understand that on sandbox it was possible for Spring 22 to be present, but on production org in the end on December - I guess it is not the case.

Comment: Or maybe you are right: first error on sandbox we got  on January the 12th, Spring 22 was already deployed on sandboxes. And 2 developer orgs started to fail on February the 5th, I guess they got into second release weekend. 
Thank you @PhilW, I was wondering what happened.