# Spring 22: DML operation Delete not allowed on List<CUSTOM OBJECT>

Tags: apex, dml, scheduled

Similar situation to wanwan at:
[DML operation Delete not allowed on List<CUSTOM OBJECT>](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369714/dml-operation-delete-not-allowed-on-listcustom-object?newreg=bf0d3727e4fc45849497836d86b7f858)
But I dont have reputation to be able to comment :-(

Customers of our app started getting issues as soon as the first Spring '22 releases happened a couple of weekends ago (Feb 5 I think) and now across the board since all have been migrated.  It actually started within an hour of the Spring 22 release.

We also have a scheduled job that invokes a class which ultimately is trying:

```
custom_obj[] dbEvents = [SELECT id, blah FROM custom_obj where Id in :ids];
delete dbEvents;
```

We started receiving:

```
Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
blah: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
blah: DML operation Delete not allowed on List<Custom_Obj>
```

We've tried recompiling all classes/triggers.  I've tried a whole new package built with everything upgraded to API 54.0 but the problem still occurs.  This made me think it must be the scheduled jobs holding on to the class version they were scheduled with (our jobs survive between upgrades).  So I deleted the jobs and they were re-scheduled using the new package code built against 54.0.  This still didnt help so now I'm thinking maybe it is a permission to delete all on the custom object that has been impacted by Spring '22?

Anyway any help or other people seeing the same thing would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark Spooner

Answer (score 3):

We have recently encountered this problem, too. This happens if you schedule a job from PostInstallHandler (my related question: [Debug Logs for PostInstallHandler SuperUser](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365594/debug-logs-for-postinstallhandler-superuser)).

For me, it helped to build new version of app in which I aborted previously scheduled jobs (that were scheduled from PostInstallHandler by a SuperUser mentioned in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have)) and added possibility to run this scheduled job from real System Administrator (in my case - it is an Apex method called from VF page).

So the actual solution is to reschedule your jobs under actual System Administrator that has permissions on your managed package custom object on delete.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Mariia, it was very helpful.  I have now tried modifying our post install code etc to use without sharing in the hope that it would fix things but it didn't seem to have any effect.  Our app is not very UI focussed as it happens, having just one config screen, but I have taken your approach and removed the job scheduling as part of the post install in favour of scheduling them via a UI click on our config screen and, although I wont say its fixed just yet, early signs are promising!

Comment: Without sharing isn't helping here unfortunately, was my first attempt as well. Hope it will work for you with some UI