# InstallHandler Scheduled Apex not Running

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, postinstall, amazon-s3

I have an installHandler running post install to create a scheduled Apex job that runs a batch Apex operation to an AWS S3 bucket. I am able to run the batch operation and run the scheduler using the Anonymous Apex Window in the Dev Console.  Everything that is run or scheduled by my user in the Org (via anonymous Apex) runs successfully with all Account records being written in the JSON to the S3 bucket but when the operation is scheduled by the installHandler the batch job is not completely successful.

What I mean by "not completely successful" is that operations that move Salesforce data to S3 do not run successfully, I have an operation that dumps a metadata JSON to the S3 bucket that runs from the finish method in the Database.Batchable class successfully (that file is created) but the JSON files that depend on Salesforce data to create the JSON files from the execute method do not.

I notice that there is a different user that the operation runs under if scheduled from the post installer that seems to be derived from the user/org IDs from our packaging org. I have looked up this issue and the consensus is to provide a "without sharing" designation in the post installer, scheduler, and batchable class definitions to allow this user to operate. I have done this with **no success**.
Can anyone help?

Comment: There are fundamental issues with the "[ghost user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have)" - I assume this is the Q&A you are referring to. There are options to assign permission sets etc. to this ghost user to help with permission-related issues, and I suspect that this is the root of your problem. However, it might be better to provide a post-install admin page to allow an appropriate admin user to schedule these jobs once the package is in place.

Comment: Basically, it is currently not a good idea to have the post install script initiate any long-running (async, scheduled) processes that need to do callouts, send emails and various other things because of these limitations. I had a conversation with the packaging product manager, Dileep Burki (`@burki_db` on Twitter), about this a few months ago and there are some longer term plans to revisit how this special user will work, but it is low priority.