# Unrecognised USER_ID value in response body when querying Event Log Files

Tags: soql, eventlogfile

As per the steps outlined [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&type=1), I have been querying the EventLogFiles and I can see that the response body has an attribute called USER_ID as per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_apitotalusage.htm). However, the user Id (it starts with 005) doesn't exist. I don't understand why the value in USER_ID doesn't exist in my org?

Comment: It's early for Halloween but ghosts are always around, here's one: [boo](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32607/installhandler-runs-under-a-special-ghost-user-what-rights-does-it-have) . There are other examples of this, do a search.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the link. The official documentation is lacking on this matter.